# Mock a return value of a method with PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking

I want to mock a method of a class to return specific value:

```
$this->mock
    ->method('method')
    ->willReturn($this->returnValue('foo'))
;
```

This method will be invoked internally by another method which will use it's result. The method is actually being mocked but it returns this:

```
class PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Stub_Return#471 (1) {
  protected $value =>
  string(3) "foo"
}
```

instead of a string. And the code which uses this method internally breaks.

How can I make a mock return a real string instead of this object?

I tried the `returnCallback` but it returns something even more weird...

`PHPUnit` v5.7.19

`PHP` v7.1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `PHPUnit` API incorrectly. It should read as follows:

```
$this->mock
    ->method('method')
    ->will($this->returnValue('foo'))
;
```

Note `->will` instead of `->willReturn`.